# how to convert this curl command to java HttpGet

Tags: java, http, curl, nullpointerexception

there is such a curl command:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u XXX:YYY https://someUrl/customer/v1/85230000105
```

where XXX is a username , YYY  is a password ,  and 85230000105 is  the parameter need send to web service

I  try to write java code like this :

```
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://someUrl/customer/v1/85230000105");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("username", "XXX");
        request.addHeader("password", "YYY");
```

Is this conversion correct?  when I  run the curl command directly, I  can get reply success, but when I do

```
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

this will raise an exception, here is  the exception picture :
[image]

please help me to find the reason.

Comment: `-H` are headers. Username and password are not headers. They are an authorization parameter. Also I think headers are case sensitive

Comment: thank you  ,  let me try to  find how to add authorization parameter into httpget

Comment: anyone know how to add this "curl -u XXX:YYY" into java httpget